# How to write a script to iteratively search through a document and return results based on a pattern

Tags: python, regex, iteration

I have a large document containing items that appear in a specific pattern:
"TEXT I NEED"
"," (Comma ends text I want to return)
"more text I DON'T need"
"." "TEXT I NEED" (need the text immediately following a period)
"," (Comma ends text).. and so on.

I am hoping to write a script that will go through the doc and pull out (TEXT I NEED).

I haven't tried much. I've tried playing around with re.compile but I am mostly a beginner.

Document example:
APPLES ARE FUN, oranges are better.
ORANGES ARE FUN, bananas are better.
BANANAS ARE WEIRD, bananas are a little weird.

I want to return:
APPLES ARE FUN
ORANGES ARE FUN
BANANAS ARE WEIRD

Comment: looks like you only want to return the uppercase words.. right?

Comment: At first you need to know what exacle the pattern is. Is it that everything you need is in uppercase?

Comment: also try to add your document structure like how the data is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract text that is before `','` and preceded by `begin of text(^)` or `'.'`:

```
import re

text = """APPLES ARE FUN, oranges are better. ORANGES ARE FUN, bananas are better. BANANAS ARE WEIRD, bananas are a little weird"""

print(re.findall('(?:^|\.\s+)([\w\s]+)(?=,)', text))
# ['APPLES ARE FUN', 'ORANGES ARE FUN', 'BANANAS ARE WEIRD']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want capital ASCII letters, that looks like this:

```
[A-Z]+
```

- The square brackets define a collection of things to match
- The hyphen defines a range, in this case from capital A to capital Z
- The plus sign says at least one of these characters in this range, but possibly more if they are next to each other

Example:

http://regexr.com/4n1s1

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('[A-Z]+')
matches = pattern.findall('APPLES ARE FUN, oranges are better. ORANGES ARE FUN, bananas are better')
print(matches)
# ['APPLES', 'ARE', 'FUN', 'ORANGES', 'ARE', 'FUN']
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on your pattern you could use something like follows:

```
from re import findall as regexSearch

with open("./myFileName.txt", "r") as myFile:
    content = myFile.read()

pattern = r"[A-Z ]{2,}"
matches = regexSearch(pattern, content)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

a good tool for testing patterns is [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). It also explains what it found and why it found it.